# com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility what use instead in JSF 1.2

Tags: java, jsf, viewexpiredexception

When I have javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException I want to send user to login page.

web.xml

```
...
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
...
 <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/errors/sessionExpired.jsf</location>
 </error-page>
```

sessionExpired.jsf

```
....
<c:redirect url="/index.jsf" />
```

but enableRestoreView11Compatibility is method that was used in JSF 1.1, what is solution for JSF 1.2?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility` is a JSF 1.2 setting that tells JSF 1.2 to behave like JSF 1.1.

`com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility` == `true` means "do not throw a `ViewExpiredException`; instead, just create a new view if the old one has expired."

The [IBM notes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rweb_jsf_custom_props.html) on the JSF 1.1 behaviour say:

> This can have adverse behaviors because it is a new view, and items that are usually in the view, such as state, are no longer be there.

The default JSF 1.2 behaviour is defined in [the spec](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/reference/api/index.html) as this:

> If the request is a postback, call `ViewHandler.restoreView()`, passing the `FacesContext` instance for the current request and the view identifier, and returning a `UIViewRoot` for the restored view. If the return from `ViewHandler.restoreView()` is null, throw a `ViewExpiredException` with an appropriate error message. javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException`is a`FacesException` that must be thrown to signal to the application that the expected view was not returned for the view identifier. An application may choose to perform some action based on this exception.

To have a `ViewExpiredException` thrown when the view expires, **remove the `com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility` parameter** or set it to `false`.

---

*The `com.sun` namespace suggests that the parameter is a Sun/Mojarra and derived implementation-specific setting, so it probably will not work with all JSF implementations.*

Comment: I thought that I can use <error-page> ... to redirect user to login page, but without this compatibility parameter this doesn't work. I need to write my PhaseListener to do this redirection, or maybe there is some easy way.

Comment: Is this setting still valid in JSF 2.2 or there is any ither option?