# Primefaces datatable onRowSelect method causing nullpointer exception

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, nullpointerexception

I am using Hibernate 4, Spring 3 and JSF 2.0 with Weblogic 10.3.6 as server. I am loading my datatable using lazy loading.

JSF Page

```
  <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="req" lazy="true" value="#{emp.lazyModel}"
                paginator="true" rows="10" 
                             selection="#{emp.selectedRequest}"
                            selectionMode="single">                         
          <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{emp.onRowSelect}" />
```

When I select a row in a datatable I am getting null pointer exception in `onRowSelect` method.

ManagedBean

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        try {

            this.setRequestNo(event.getObject().toString());            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }

    }
```

In LazyEmpDataModel I have the following methods

```
@Override
    public void setRowIndex(final int rowIndex) {
        if (rowIndex == -1 || getPageSize() == 0) {
            super.setRowIndex(-1);
        } else {
            super.setRowIndex(rowIndex % getPageSize());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Employees emp) {
        return request.getRequestNo();
    }

@Override
    public Employees getRowData(String rowKey) {
        for (Employees emp : requestList) {
            if (emp.getEmpNo().equals(rowKey))
                return emp;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Full stackexception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.test.managed.bean.RequestManagedBean.onRowSelect(RequestManagedBean.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:187)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:52)
    at org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent.processListener(SelectEvent.java:40)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1071)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: what is that line exactly ?

Comment: @Daniel This line is causing NPE `this.setRequestNo(event.getObject().toString());`

Comment: so debug it... what is null ? `event.getObject()` ?

Comment: I am trying to get the rowkey with that. I tried this as well `((Emp) event.getObject()).getEmpNo());`

Comment: Try a different version of PrimeFaces.  Even going to the next or previous minor version may make a difference.  Complex functionalities in PrimeFaces such as dataTables sometimes change significantly between minor versions.

Comment: @Polppan to be on the safe side , try Emp my_emp = (Emp) event.getObject()); System.out.println(my_emp.getEmpNo() );

Comment: @Daniel `Emp my_emp = (Emp) event.getObject());`  didn't help. I have noticed that another thing is when I click on a row in datatable, first time no error message appear, if I click for the second time on another row, then exception throws.

Comment: INMO its something wit your view scope bean , try making it session... if session will help , post a question about your view scope bean

Comment: @Daniel Yes with session scope I could get the empNo of the row I selected. With Request and View it didn't. What's wrong with View and Request scope?

Comment: Since I'm not a CDI / Spring user I can't help you , I think that with JSF view scope it should work just fine

Comment: @Daniel Yes I am using CDI/Spring.

Comment: maybe you are using the view scope wrong... maybe its being invalidated for some reason... ask a view scope specific question.. add a post constructor to your bean with print lines and see if its indeed being reconstructed upon pagination / row selection

Comment: @Daniel FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041087/primefaces-datatable-selected-row-not-working-using-viewscope

Comment: @Daniel I have noticed another thing is using view scope when I paginate to second page and then comes back to first page, then I could get the selectedRow. Otherwise NPE.

Comment: @Daniel If you provide an answer with what you mentioned in comments that it will not work because I was using View scope, I will be glad to accept it. Thanks. BTW I have managed to resolve the [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041087/primefaces-datatable-selected-row-not-working-using-viewscope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INMO its something with your `view scope` bean , try making it session... if session will help  look for a way to work properly with CDI View bean

Maybe its being invalidated for some reason... Add a post constructor to your bean with print lines and see if its indeed being reconstructed upon pagination / row selection